# Would the SMSG textbooks provide adequate extracurricular study?

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks, self-learning, reference-books

Context: I'm a Grade 11 IBDP student and very fond of math. Assuming that I get the spare time to self-study material alongside the syllabus, I wish to spend it constructively (the only step I've taken thus far in learning mathematics is to complete HS math courses on Khan Academy up to and including Integral Calculus). I want to tackle a heavy-duty calculus book like Spivak or Apostol before entering college (if you feel aspiring mathematicians in HS would be better served by other objectives, please share them in your answer).

I decided against compiling a list of textbooks from various sources and followed the advice given in [this answer on Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/should-i-become-a-mathematician.122924/post-1006099) (an arbitrary choice; I just thought it was a well-written answer), which mentioned the SMSG textbooks. I am, however, concerned about their obsolescence.

Are these textbooks still relevant? Would I be better off learning different topics from a variety of publishers (like the books recommended on [this webpage](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Eabhishek/chicmath.htm) or in [this question](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/did-i-choose-the-right-books-for-relearning-math-geometry-algebra-logic-and-proofs.988171/)?

Comment: The list at https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm is formidable and has some good insight. Still it misses a lot of recent great books in the Springer line etc. For the Physics forum answer, I would encourage you to not focus merely on those recommendations. There are other excellent cheap choices... sorry to be vague, time is tight today.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18551/what-are-the-resources-to-learn-prerequisite-knowledge-to-latter-high-school-and

Comment: What makes you think that you're not prepared for Spivak and Apostol? Dive in and try.

Comment: I recommend the SMSG books a lot in my Stack Exchange comments and answers (mainly comments I suspect), but in my opinion they're better for gaining a broader insight into mathematics over a longer period of time than you have available (unless you pick a specific one for a specific topic, like [**Introduction to Matrix Algebra**](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED135632.pdf) or [**Analytic Geometry**](http://stern.buffalostate.edu/newmath/SMSG/64analygeomStud.pdf)). Better for your pre-Spivak/Apostol reading are [the Gelfand books](https://www.google.com/search?q=Gelfand+school+books).

Comment: As @Ben Crowell suggests, it's probably best to dive right in with Spivak or Apostol, unless you feel that your background is especially weak in some topic you'd like to brush up on first (trig. identities and the many applications of De Moivre's formula, for example). The Gelfand books don't require a huge investment of time if you've seen much of the material before, and provide a lot of the insights that often get omitted in school texts and school classes designed for audiences with goals and abilities different from yours. **(continued)**

Comment: I recommend Apostol over Spivak because Apostol's calculus provide a much greater breadth in precalculus and calculus topics. Spivak is rather narrowly focused on pure "real analysis type" topics in comparison to Apostol.

Comment: @Ben Crowell I did. And the questions following the first chapter in Spivak were unlike anything I had done before. This was a few months ago, though, so I'll give it another shot.

Comment: @Ben Crowell, However, I love that 'Aha!' moment that comes with peeking into the answer key after musing over a question for 10 minutes. I like learning this way too. I only felt that I was taking too ambitious a step and was apprehensive of the difficulty of future questions in the book.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Until now, I had never heard of De Moivre's formula (feels like an ill omen to me); my explorations in math were limited to Khan Academy. I just wanted to know which of the Gelfand books I should read, and in what order. Would these be appropriate: Algebra, Functions and Graphs, The Method of Coordinates, Geometry, Trigonometry and, finally, Calculus of Variations (or straight to Apostol?)? Also, it seems like I'm missing a Combinatorics book. Thank you for your recommendations and advice!

Comment: Perhaps first *Algebra*, then *Trigonometry*, then *Functions and Graphs*. These first two will take the most time, and Functions and Graphs should go quick but a lot of the methods in it will be extremely useful in calculus (being able to quickly hand-sketch "basic graphs" will be very helpful in max/min analysis and in setting up definite integrals for areas). *The Method of Coordinates* is a fun book that can be read at any time, but it isn't all that important for specific content or skills you'll need soon.

Comment: [*Sequences, Combinations, Limits*](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486425665) is a book of problems with detailed solutions, and the material on sequences and limits is especially relevant for calculus, but since much of what you'll be doing in Apostol or Spivak will involve similar material, I don't recommend trying to do this prior to calculus, but instead just look over it from time to time. Gelfand's *Calculus of Variations* is something much more advanced that you should not consider for several years (if ever; it's a subject that one could easily not study even when getting a Ph.D.).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Noted. Thank you for your help.